# Which building regulations in Europe for industrial buildings should I read if I want build bus factory in Europe?

Tags: regulations

I want to build a bus factory in Europe (for example in Austria). Which documents about building regulations should I read to construct correctly (I know that there are Eurocodes, but maybe there is some more documents with basic information)?

Answer (score 1):

Building (and planning) regulations are a national matter (although the regulations may serve to give effect to EU directives).  Therefor you will have to read the Austrian building regulations if you want to know what they are. "Bauordnung" is the term to search for, and [this](https://www.oesterreich.gv.at/themen/bauen_wohnen_und_umwelt/bauen/Seite.2260200.html) seems like the relevant government website.

However, I suspect that for a factory (as distinct from a self-build cottage †) you are going to need sign-off from a qualified architect and/or civil engineer - and they would already know this.  Reading the regulations themselves is unlikely to be a fruitful way for somebody who is not a building professional to learn what is required.

† Note that Austria may well require sign-off from a qualified professional even for a self-build cottage.